# Notice: Undefined index: placa in C:\xampp\htdocs\ControlAsistencia\registro.php on line 8

Tags: php, html

necesito una ayuda con un código php

intento registrar datos en una base de datos atravez de un formulario pero me aparece este error

Notice: Undefined index: placa in C:\xampp\htdocs\ControlAsistencia\registro.php on line 8
Error. ID ya registrado

Pero el ID que supuesta mente ya esta registrado no esta registrado, no esta el ID ni ningún dato repetido en la base de datos

se agrego el campo placa en todos los archivos y Base de datos pero no funciona no entiendo por que

este es el código HTML

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Control de Asistencia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pompiere|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
</script>

<!--Header cutre-->
<div class="row blue white-text z-depth-1">
  <div class="col l8 offset-l2 m10 offset-m1 s12 center header">
    <h2>Control de Asistencia</h2>
    <h3>Registrar Integrantes</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Inicio de menú colapsable-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col l6 offset-l3 m8 offset-m2 s12 z-depth-1">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">





<!--Sección para registrar a los becarios en el sistema-->
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons blue-text darken-2">library_add</i>Registrar becario</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          <div class="row center">
            <form class="col l6 offset-l3 m8 offset-m2 s12" action="" onsubmit="registrarBecario(); return false" name="nuevo_becario">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field"> 
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="nickname">ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nickname" name="nickname" required="true">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field"> 
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="name">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required="true">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field"> 
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="placa">Placa</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="placa" name="placa" required="true">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field"> 
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required="true">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn blue lighten-2">Registrar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="row center" id="estado_registro"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Fin de menú colapsable-->

</body>
</html>
```

este es el archivo registro.php

```
<?php

require 'database.php';

// guardar valores post
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$placa = $_POST['placa'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// insert data
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Becarios (nickname,name,placa,password,status) values(?,?,?,?,'INACTIVO')";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
try {
      $q->execute(array($nickname,$name,$placa,$password));
      echo '<span class="green-text">Registro exitoso.</span>';
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<span class="red-text">Error. ID ya registrado</span>';
}
Database::disconnect();
exit();
```

?>

y la base de datos tiene los mismos nombres en el mismo orden
Si quito la variable de placa en todo lado funciona sin problemas pero al agregarla no funciona

Me podrían ayudar por favor

```
function registrarBecario(){

    //div donde se mostrará lo resultados
    divResultado = document.getElementById('estado_registro');

    //Se obtienen los datos del formulario
    nickname=document.nuevo_becario.nickname.value;
    name=document.nuevo_becario.name.value;
    placa=document.nuevo_becario.placa.value;
    password=document.nuevo_becario.password.value;

    //Instanciamos el objetoAjax
    ajax=objetoAjax();

    //Uso del metodo POST
    ajax.open("POST","registro.php",true);

    //Cuando el objeto XMLHttpRequest cambia de estado, la función se inicia
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        //La función responseText tiene todos los datos pedidos al servidor
        if (ajax.readyState==4) {
            //Mostrar resultados en esta capa
            divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
            //Llamar a funcion para limpiar el formulario
            LimpiarCamposRegistro();
        }
    }
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //Enviando los valores para su procesamiento
    ajax.send("nickname="+nickname+"&name="+name+"$placa="+placa+"&password="+password)
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código javascript de la función `registrarBecario();`, seguramente ahí estás omitiendo agregar el campo.

Comment: Listos, ya adicione la parte de RegistrarBecario()

Comment: El problema es que a la hora de enviar los datos en el ajax has puesto `"$placa="` y debería ser `"&placa="` por eso no llega la información.

Comment: Oohhh por un pequeño error, muchas muchas gracias ya funciona. Enserio muchas gracias

Comment: @BrayanLopez De nada, para eso estamos. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta exactamente en esta linea:

`ajax.send("nickname="+nickname+"&name="+name+"$placa="+placa+"&password="+password)`

ya que esta escrito `"$placa="` y deberia ser `"&placa="` por eso no llega el valor. Saludos.